# Benchmark Testing - posix-aio vs libaio

Tags: python, benchmarking

In order to perform a relevant/reliable benchmark testing, how do I known whether an application is using libaio or the posix-aio ? is there a way to force an application to use libaio/posix-aio ?

When using python standard read\write - which library is used?

BR,
 Curious

Answer (score 1):

> how do I known whether an application is using libaio or the posix-aio

You could use `strace` and look at the syscalls. If the program is using
`libaio` then `libaio` will eventually have to call one of the KAIO syscalls
such as `io_submit()` (see
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html ). On Linux, POSIX AIO is currently (2019) only implemented in userland by glibc so will never make those syscalls. I suppose if the libraries are dynamically linked you could use `ltrace` to work out what was happening too...

> is there a way to force an application to use libaio/posix-aio ?

Not without a rewrite of the original source. The APIs for POSIX AIO / KAIO are different to those for regular POSIX I/O and the API for POSIX AIO is different to that for KAIO.

> When using python standard read\write - which library is used?

On Linux, a standard Python read/write call will use neither POSIX AIO nor KAIO - it will make a basic POSIX I/O call which will be implemented by whatever C library you're linking against (e.g. glibc). See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5be666010e4df65dc4d831435cc92340ea369f94/Python/fileutils.c#L1529 for where a basic `read()` call is done.